# How can I add in code to make it impossible for a user to input an answer that is not listed? C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Kenneth_ForquerENG_115
    {
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Kenneth Forquer ENG 115");
```

This is where i store my questions and answers

```
        List<Question> question = new List<Question>
        {


            new Question("What stage bleed air is used to start the engine?", new string[] { "8th", "9th", "1st", "13th" }, Question.multipleChoice, 2),
            new Question("Igniters spark to combust the fuel.", new string[] { "true", "false" }, Question.trueAndFalse, 0),
            new Question("What is the 1st stage in the cycle of the Gas turbine?", new string[] { "Intake", "Exhaust", "Power", "Combustion" }, Question.multipleChoice, 0),
            new Question("What is the 3rd stage in the cycle of the Gas turbine?", new string[] { "Compression", "Combustion", "Intake", "Exhaust" }, Question.multipleChoice, 1),
            new Question(" What is the last stage in the cycle of the Gas turbine?", new string[] { "Compression", "Power", "Intake", "Exhaust" }, Question.multipleChoice, 3),
            new Question("Ngg refers to speed.", new string[] { "true", "false" }, Question.trueAndFalse, 0),
            new Question("Npt refers to torque", new string[] { "true", "false" }, Question.trueAndFalse, 1),
            new Question("What are the LM2500 metering points?", new string[] { "3", "2", "5.4", "All of the above" }, Question.multipleChoice, 3),
            new Question("Which of these are a component of the compressor?", new string[] { "Inlet Plenum", "Gearbox", "Stator", "All of the above" }, Question.multipleChoice, 2),
            new Question("What company manufactures the LM2500?", new string[] { "GM", "Ford", "Toyota", "Rolls Royce" }, Question.multipleChoice, 3)
        };


        for (int i = 0; i < question.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Question #" + (1 + i).ToString());
            if (question[i].Ask())
            {
                Results.AddResult(question[i]);
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue to the next question.");
                //Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
            }
            else
            {
                Results.AddResult(question[i]);
            }
            Console.Clear();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("End of the first attempt.");
        int tempScore = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Results.firstResults.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Results.firstResults[i].isCorrect)
            {
                tempScore++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Your current mark is: " + tempScore + "/" + Results.firstResults.Count.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();

        Results.RunSecondAttemp();

        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("End of the Quiz!");

        int tempFinalScore = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Results.finalResults.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Results.finalResults[i].isCorrect)
            {
                tempFinalScore++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Your final mark is: ");
        Console.WriteLine(tempFinalScore + "/" + Results.finalResults.Count.ToString());
        if (tempFinalScore > 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Good Job!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Better luck next time...");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit the console...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
}

 namespace Kenneth_ForquerENG_115
{
class Question
{
    public string question;
    public string[] answers;
    public bool isCorrect;
    public string inputAnswer;
    private int correctIndex;
    private string questionType;
    public static string trueAndFalse = "TF";
    public static string multipleChoice = "MC";
```

Here is where the input for the questions are.

```
    public Question(string q, string[] answersList, string typeOfQuestion, int correctAnswer)
    {
        question = q;
        questionType = typeOfQuestion;
        if (questionType == multipleChoice)
            answers = new string[4];
        else if (questionType == trueAndFalse)
            answers = new string[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < answersList.Length; i++)
        {
            this.answers[i] = answersList[i];
        }

        correctIndex = correctAnswer;
    }


    public bool Ask()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(question);
        if (questionType == multipleChoice)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input an answer from the following possibilities...");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please input 'true' or 'false'... ");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < answers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(answers[i]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
        inputAnswer = Console.ReadLine();


        if (inputAnswer == answers[correctIndex])
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
            isCorrect = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue to the next question.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect.");
            isCorrect = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue to the next question.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        return isCorrect;
    }

    public void PrintQuestion()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(question);
        if (questionType == multipleChoice)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input an answer from the following possibilities...");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please input 'true' or 'false'... ");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < answers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(answers[i]);
        }
    }
}
}

namespace Kenneth_ForquerENG_115
{
    static class Results
    {
        public static List<Question> firstResults = new List<Question>();
        public static List<Question> finalResults = new List<Question>();


        public static void AddResult(Question questionResult)
        {
            firstResults.Add(questionResult);
        }

        public static void AddFinalResult(Question question)
        {
            finalResults.Add(question);
        }

        public static void RunSecondAttemp()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Attempt #2:");

            for (int i = 0; i < firstResults.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("\nQuestion " + (1 + i).ToString());

                if (firstResults[i].isCorrect)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nThis one was correct!");
                    firstResults[i].PrintQuestion();
                    Console.WriteLine("Your answer: " + firstResults[i].inputAnswer);
                    AddFinalResult(firstResults[i]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue to the next question.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This one was wrong on the first attempt! Please try again.");
                    if (firstResults[i].Ask())
                    {
                        AddFinalResult(firstResults[i]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue to the next question.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddFinalResult(firstResults[i]);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------");
                }

                Console.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is make it where the user can only input the answers to the questions. If they type in something not listed it will display an error message, something like "incorrect input, please choose from given answers." So if they type something not listed that message would appear and then go back to the question until they type on of the choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to check if their answer is among the answer choices before checking if the answer is correct. You could do it like this:

```
while (Array.IndexOf(answers, inputAnswer) < 0)
{          
    Console.WriteLine("incorrect input, please choose from given answers.");
    inputAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

`Array.IndexOf` will return `-1` if `inputAnswer` is not in the `answers` array. The `while` loop will not break until the user inputs an answer that is in the `answers` array, and `inputAnswer` will contain an answer that is in `answers` when the loop breaks.

This would go in the `Ask` method before the line containing

```
if (inputAnswer == answers[correctIndex])
```

Comment: Wow that seems so simple now. Thank you so much That is exactly what I needed.